# How do i save a page so it stays the same

Tags: javascript, html

So i have been asked to make a table that contained 4 grids and 2 rows, and a button that basically adds more rows with more information in them, i have managed to do all that but the tricky question is that i need to be able to somehow transport all of the information onto an excel like database so that it always saves, and when they need to bring said html page the information is shown there not just 2 rows and 4 grids

I have tried many things such as connecting an excel towards the page and searched through google but nothing.

Comment: I do not cleary understand what you are trying to achieve. So you are creating the rows via JavaScript?

Comment: Direct integration with Excel etc will be hard, the best way I know this could work is to convert your data into a CSV or TSV file that Excel can read, and excel can export that to a format readable by the browser again (since it's just text)

Comment: sorry if its weird, i suck at explaining problems, you know how you add user input into a variable and it stays there until you reload the page, well i need to somehow keep that variable even after reloading the page or export that variable onto another program

Comment: Either you need to store the data in the browser (e.g. `localStorage`), or on a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you asking for a `localStorage` so when you reload the page the data/info will stay.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

I can advise to read this. I think this is what you are aiming for.

Comment: i indeed was looking for this, thank you kind sir/madam its going to be hard to actually save an entire table

Comment: Another option would be to use IndexedDB, which has a more generous limit on size and is already a table structure, but is also more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your work as a CSV or TSV, and then you can use [FileReader.readAsText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) to read it when page loads and with the returned string, you can construct tables. CSV/TSV files can be opened in spreadsheet softwares including Excel.